# API to mix 2 mp3 files

Tags: android, file, mp3

I am trying to mix two mp3 files in my Android application.Is there any api available using which I can do it.Please help me regarding this?

Comment: Do you mean "I want to play both files back at the same time", or do you mean "I want to create a third MP3 file that contains the blended contents of the first two MP3 files"?

Comment: I want to create a third MP3 file that contains the blended contents of the first two MP3 files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into Android for this sort of audio file manipulation. You may be able to find some existing Java JARs or Linux libraries that you could repurpose for this.

Comment: Ok.Thank you.You have any idea about Java JAR's that could be used.And Do JARs work directly with android or I have to do something else?

Comment: @VinodDsouza: "You have any idea about Java JAR's that could be used" -- no. "And Do JARs work directly with android or I have to do something else?" -- that depends on the JAR.

Comment: Ok.Please let me know,if you come across any JARs.

Comment: If I want to play both files back at the same time,Do I have to use a thread?